# Applying 3D rotation matrix to x, y, z values obtained from surface function

Tags: matlab, octave

Applying 3D rotation matrix to the x,y,z values obtained from surface function object.  The error I get is due to the matrix not being nonconforment but how can I adjust the matrix correctly?

I know hgtransform / makehgtform can do rotations but **I need to use rotation matrices since I plan on testing it using matrices created from quaternions**.

I've created a little plane out of cylinders and the surface functions.
See code below:

```
clear all,clf

ax=axes('XLim',[-2 2],'YLim', [-2 10],'ZLim',[-1.5 1.5]);
grid on;
%axis equal;
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('z');
ax

% rotate around
rot_mat = [.707 -.707 0;.707 .707 0; 0 0 1] %rotation matrix

[xc yc zc] = cylinder([0.1 0.0]); %cone
[x y z]= cylinder([0.2 0.2]);


h(1) = surface(xc,zc,-yc,'FaceColor', 'red'); %noise cone
h(2) = surface(z,y,0.5*x,'FaceColor', 'blue'); %right wing
h(3) = surface(-z,y,0.5*x,'FaceColor', 'yellow');%left wing
h(4) = surface(x,-1.5*z,0.5*y,'FaceColor', 'green'); %main body
h(5) = surface(xc,(1.5*yc)-1.3,z*.5,'FaceColor', 'red'); %tail

view(3);

x_temp = get(h(1),'xdata'); % get x values
y_temp = get(h(1),'ydata');
z_temp =get(h(1),'zdata');

xc_new=x_temp.*rot_mat;
%zc_new=
%yc_new=
```

[image: little plane]

I can get the x,y, and z value by using the commands

```
x_temp = get(h(1),'xdata');
y_temp = get(h(1),'ydata');
z_temp = get(h(1),'zdata');
```

The error I get is due to the matrix being nonconforment but **how can I adjust the matrix correctly?**

error: test_object_matrix_rot: product: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x21, op2 is 3x3).

The error is with the line **xc_new=x_temp.*rot_mat;**

**PS: I'm using Octave 5.0.91  which is like Matlab**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu are messing up a lot of things......in fact I would say, you have made your work complex. YOu should straight away work on matrices to rotate to new positons instead of arrays and picking them from the figure.

This line:

```
x_temp = get(h(1),'xdata'); % get x values
```

giving you a 2*21 array and your rot_mat is 3X3.....you cannot multiply them. YOu need to pick (x,y,z) and multiply this point with rotation matrix to get the point shifted. Check the below pseudo code.....yo can develop your logic with the below example code.

```
t = 0:0.1:1;
[X,Y,Z] = cylinder((t));

%% Rotation 
th = pi/2 ;
Rx = [1 0 0 ; 0 cos(th) -sin(th) ; 0 sin(th) cos(th)] ;
P0 = [X(:) Y(:) Z(:)] ;
P1 = P0*Rx ;

X1 = reshape(P1(:,1),size(X)) ;
Y1 = reshape(P1(:,2),size(X)) ;
Z1 = reshape(P1(:,3),size(X)) ;

figure
hold on
surf(X,Y,Z)
surf(X1,Y1,Z1)

view(3)
```

Comment: Thanks!!  That helped a lot